# then running before ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a function after an ajax return has completed using `then`, but it seems to be running before the return. My code is as follows:

```
  var existingUser = false;

  $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/ajax/signup',
                data: { signup_email: signupEmail },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.message == 'The email address '+signupEmail+' has already been registered.') {
                        existingUser = true;
                        console.log('truth!')
                    }
                }
            }
        )
            .then(console.log(existingUser))
```

Which I would expect to log

```
truth!
true
```

if the return has the expected message, but is instead logging

```
false
truth!
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why dont you move the success handler  from ajax to the success handler inside to avoid problems in the sequence in which the two are being called

Comment: console.log(value) is ran immediately. clearly you meant to put that into a callback function but failed to do so.

Comment: why use `then()` and `success()` ? seems confusing, and evidently, it is..

Comment: So this is an oversimplified example. I actually have a chain of functions I want to run in succession. The `console.log` is just there for a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that is passed to `then` should be a function. In your case, the console.log is getting executed immediately hence the output that you get.

Refer to these two examples
http://jsfiddle.net/9L7dD/12/
http://jsfiddle.net/9L7dD/13/

Comment: @wogsland funny, this is exactly the point i was making about the console.log in my comment. :)

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, but apparently I needed it spelled out in a little more detail to get it through my thick head ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function call launching the ajax request finishes before the ajax request is completed. In essence:

1. launch ajax request
2. output existingUser
3. output "truth"

Can you simply add your `console.log` in the `success` handler?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that your ajax request executes success upon its promise being fulfilled and receiving a response...well a non-error response. The "then" simply executes after the ajax function is run NOT upon it getting resolved (getting a response back from your url). It looks like you don't really need your console.log in a "then" statement as you're already checking in the success function if its executing properly.